# Login and getting session id of the logged using Https connection in java

Tags: java, https, http-headers

I am trying to login to a website using the https requests and then capture the session id. I need this session id inorder to delete some tags in the web application.

Till now I am able to login to the application. After being logged in the application directs me to the home page. This is where I tried to capture the session id from the cookies using https get request to the home page. But unfortunately the cookie doesnot contain session id.

When I send get request to home page after being logged in I get a cookie as :
headers fields are :{null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/7.0], Pragma=[no-cache], Date=[Wed, 23 Dec 2015 04:37:13 GMT], Serv=[1], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store], SI=[1], X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], Set-Cookie=[], Expires=[-1], Content-Length=[255882], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET], Content-Type=[text/html; charset=utf-8]}

Here the Set-Cookie field is empty.

I have written the following lines of code.

```
package com.iso.mozart.test.ui;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class HttpUrlConnectionExample {

  private List<String> cookies;
  private HttpsURLConnection conn;

  private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String url = "https://www.testpurpose.com/Login.aspx";
    String homepage = "https://www.testpurpose.com/Home.aspx";

    HttpUrlConnectionExample http = new HttpUrlConnectionExample();

    // make sure cookies is turn on
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

    // 1. Send a "GET" request, so that you can extract the form's data.
    String page = http.GetPageContent(url);
    String postParams = http.getFormParams(page, "username here", "password here");

    // 2. Construct above post's content and then send a POST request for
    // authentication
    http.sendPost(url, postParams);

    // 3. success then go to homepage.

    String result = http.GetPageContent(homepage);
    System.out.println(result);
  }   

private void sendPost(String url, String postParams) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // Acts like a browser
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.testpurpose.com");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
        conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
    }
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", url);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postParams.length()));

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    // Send post request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postParams);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    //  System.out.println("HEADERS:"+conn.getRequestMethod());

    BufferedReader in = 
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    // System.out.println(response.toString());

  }

  private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // default is GET
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    // act like a browser
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    conn.getRequestProperties();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    //  System.out.println("Huhahahahah :"+conn.getHeaderFields());
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
            conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
        }
    }
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
     System.out.println("headers fields are :"+conn.getHeaderFields());
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // Get the response cookies
    setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));      //This is where I have tried to capture the session id from cookie but could it doesnot contain session id.
    return response.toString();


  }

  public String getFormParams(String html, String username, String password)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    // Google form id
    Element loginform = doc.getElementById("form1");
    Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");
    List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
        String key = inputElement.attr("name");
        String value = inputElement.attr("value");

        if (key.equals("txtUserID"))
            value = username;
        else if (key.equals("txtPassword"))
            value = password;
        paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
    }

    // build parameters list
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (String param : paramList) {
        if (result.length() == 0) {
            result.append(param);
        } else {
            result.append("&" + param);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
  }

  public List<String> getCookies() {
    return cookies;
  }

  public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
    this.cookies = cookies;
  }

}
```

Comment: You can debug and check where does session created in login!!. `i.e. getSession(); ` To verify mentioned code is trying to access after it or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
```

Change above line in your code with this line.

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: No still the same case. After being logged in it redirects me to the home page. Now when I sent a get request to the home page, I get the following in the headers:
Sending 'GET' request to URL : https://myurl.com/Home.aspx
Response Code : 200
headers fields are :{null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/7.0], Pragma=[no-cache], Date=[Wed, 23 Dec 2015 04:56:56 GMT], Serv=[1], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store], SI=[1], X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], Set-Cookie=[], Expires=[-1], Content-Length=[255882], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET], Content-Type=[text/html; charset=utf-8]}

Comment: By your url i thing you are writing your webservice and trying to access that. Am i right? In that case you need to create a session in the server side. Set-Cookie filed is empty in your print it means that your not creating the session in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String sessionid = session.getId();
```

use this small block of code.

Comment: Hi, I just want to login and get the session id of the logged in user. The website I am trying to login is not my own. I am just trying to get the session id using the Http method in java. 
Now when I tried your code, ecllipse shows that HttpSession is not recognized